# Google Document AI custom processor training failed for unknown reason

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

After annotating my data set and training a custom processor on Google Document AI, I get the following error message after 40 mins:

```
{
  "name": "projects/500809854407/locations/eu/operations/10980743890623751388",
  "done": true,
  "result": "error",
  "response": {},
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.documentai.uiv1beta3.TrainProcessorVersionMetadata",
    "commonMetadata": {
      "state": "FAILED",
      "createTime": "2023-01-13T15:11:36.505757Z",
      "updateTime": "2023-01-13T15:50:10.343765Z",
      "resource": "projects/500809854407/locations/eu/processors/b94da5023b6cb35d/processorVersions/98637063da2b64d4"
    },
    "trainingDatasetValidation": {},
    "testDatasetValidation": {}
  },
  "error": {
    "code": 13,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I agree this error message is not very helpful as is.
Can you clarify more about how you came across this issue?

What type of processor is this (I'm assuming Custom Document Extraction)?
How did you make this request (Through the Cloud Console, REST API, Client Library)?

Comment: Yes, it's custom document extraction. I started training through the cloud console. I came across this article that mentions the same error message: https://medium.com/google-cloud/document-ai-workbench-53728a6c5622

Comment: I would recommend retrying the training (if you haven't already), but this error can also occur due to non-transient issues. Can you update here if the re-training doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, will do! Is there an estimate of the duration of the training process? I love the rest of the product so far btw. The labelling UI is really good.

Comment: Glad to hear the rest of the product is working well! The training time varies a great amount depending on amount of training data, size/complexity of the document, etc. So, can't provide much of an estimate for now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.